# How to make a class that holds classes?

Tags: c#, class, reference

I want to make a program that lists recipes, their ingredients and only ingredients on a separate page.

I was thinking of creating classes "Ingredient" and "Recipe". The "Recipe" class will have a name and description properties and a `Dictionary<Ingredient, int>` property. I was thinking of filling the dictionary with "ingredient" classes and the amount they are needed in, for example let's say I create an instance of the "Recipe" class and name it "Pancakes". I will add a new `Ingredient` instance, named "Milk" to the dictionary with the amount 100 (for example) and do the same for "eggs" and so forth.

Is this the correct way to go about such a thing, as I will want to create references or links to the ingredients themselves on the "ingredients" page?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: A List of <Ingredient,amount> makes more sense, you are now abusing the dictionary to combine those 2 properties. Use a Tuple or create a Component class.

Comment: Apart from the misuse of `Dictionary`, you will soon encounter the need for a more granular unit of measure for fractions, etc.

Comment: The question is always what should the program be able to achieve. You need to divide and abstract your problem into logical units representing it and then implement these in your program logic. That can be as you described. It could also work to implement the Ingredient as a `ValueType` and just add that to the Recipe with the amount stored directly in the Ingredient type... It all depends on what you want to represent in your program.

Comment: @FCin, because I wanted advice and this is the only thing I could think of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have described will work correctly. However, a common solution for what you have described is the decorator pattern. The decorator pattern is used for creating dynamic objects.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j40kRwSm4VE

This example is using pizza and toppings but it's essentially the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
public enum UnitOfMeasurement
{
    Grams,
    Milliliters
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public UnitOfMeasurement UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }

    public decimal Unit { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public List<string> RecipeSteps { get; set; }
}
```

I might be tempted to create a class or some more complex object for recipe steps as well but that largely depends on what you want to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to do something like this recently in an interview, had to put in a recipe and then print it out by overriding the ToString() method. Obviously it can be cleaned up a lot, but the general idea is there.

came up with this code:

```
using System;

namespace cSHARP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Recipe myRecipe = new Recipe();
            Ingredient myIngredient = new Ingredient();
            Ingredient myIngredient2 = new Ingredient();

            myRecipe.Name = "Fish and Chips";

            myIngredient.Name = "Fish";
            myIngredient.Amount = 3;
            myIngredient.AmountType = "pieces";

            myIngredient2.Name = "Chips";
            myIngredient2.Amount = 1;
            myIngredient2.AmountType = "regular serving";

            myRecipe.Ingredients = new Ingredient[2];

            myRecipe.Ingredients[0] = myIngredient;
            myRecipe.Ingredients[1] = myIngredient2;

            Console.WriteLine(myRecipe.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Recipe
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Ingredient[] Ingredients { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retVal = "";

            retVal = retVal + "\n Recipe Name is " + this.Name;
            retVal = retVal + "\n Ingredient one is "
                + this.Ingredients[0].Amount.ToString() + " "
                + this.Ingredients[0].AmountType.ToString() + " of "
                + this.Ingredients[0].Name;
            retVal = retVal + "\n Ingredient two is "
                + this.Ingredients[1].Amount.ToString() + " "
                + this.Ingredients[1].AmountType.ToString() + " of "
                + this.Ingredients[1].Name;


            return (retVal);
        }
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string AmountType { get; set; }
    }
}
```